# Python - New to python; issue with random

Tags: python

I would like help with my code, and it's fairly hard to describe my issue, but I will explain below (code will also be below **warning** fairly long **warning**

I have a project where I have rooms, and a ghost follows you around these rooms.
I have given each room a number from 1 to 13 (prn) and...
I have a random module where the 'ghost' takes a random number from 1-13 (grn) and if it matches the prn, then 'BOO!' is displayed.
My issue is where I should place this piece of code.
**code insert** **LONG**

```
*******************************************************
    import random
    grn = (random.randint(1,13))
    if prn == grn:
        print(" ")
        print('BOO!')
        print(" ")
*******************************************************
house()
```

focus on the part between the stars.
I have the random module there, and grn. prn of each room is above in the while loop.
My issue is, the 'BOO!' doesn't get displayed, if grn and prn match, so I came here to ask:
where do I move this to
OR
what should I edit to get this to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the indentation level for your starred portion.  `prn` is being defined inside the while loop.  You'll only get to `if prn == grn` after the user types `exit` so you won't get the value you're expecting.

It also looks like you're passing 'room' into `loft()` as a global. That's a bad idea -- you don't know when it will change out from under you and you won't get told.

You should probably check out these answers on codereview:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36101/better-way-to-code-this-game/36112#36112
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155661/text-adventure-game

Comment: it's in the while loop of 'if it's not the exit then...' and the if statements inside this loop are 'if the 'room' is 'loft' then go to the definition of loft - which was the next line. So surely prn, because it's on the line after, should come into effect once the user is in the 'loft'.

Comment: **Thanks for helping. I managed to fix it by putting grn = (random.randint(1,13))
    if prn == grn:
        print(" ")
        print('BOO!')
        print(" ") under each room in the while loop. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Import your random Module at the very beginning of your file. Not the end

Comment: I have tried that, with no improvement. That may be a step to fixing it, but i think there's another issue somewhere.

Comment: ^^ issue fixed. It was a step towards fixing. thanks :P